# Linear like functions

Tags: real-analysis

What are some examples of functions  other than f in  f(x)= x which satisfy

g(x) = x ,  *only when* x is an integer. I visualize a variable

that oscillates with nodal eigenvalues at the cardinal numbers.

Comment: Do you want find functions such that $g(x)=x$ for integers $x$ and $g(x)\ne x$ if $x$ isn't integer?

Comment: How about $g(x)=x+\sin(\pi x)$?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza yep

Comment: You could get any function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=x$ and add to it function $h(x)$ such that $h(x)=0$ only in integers $x$. $h(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ is a greate example

Comment: @ Batominovski Yes, roots of all such g(x)- x having domain periodicity.

Comment: This is not functional analysis.